# Laravel tinker won't start because of a missing Termfile?

Tags: php, laravel, readline, tinker

I've just tried to start tinker in my Laravel 8 project, I'm working on a Windows 10 PC with Mamp, I'm running PHP 7.4

When I run `php artisan tinker` I get an error:

> Terminfo file does not exist

I've never seen this error ever before, what's going on here:

[image]

Comment: can you check if `ext-pdo-sqlite` extension is enabled in your php installation? and enable it if it doesn't (my suggest is based on [this PR comments](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/pull/300#issuecomment-220239533)

Comment: It's installed, I've never uninstalled it: `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

Comment: just checked in my working laravel project with php74 - i don't have even `Hoa` folder in `Readline`, what is the installed version of physh do you have? (my 0.10.8)

Answer (score 2):

I made downgrade of version and it works fine for me

> composer require psy/psysh:0.11.2

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your machine doesn't have "[terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)", which the readline implementation of PsySH uses to figure out how to support your terminal.

This next release of PsySH will have [a fix which automatically downgrades to a fallback readline implementation when it can't find terminfo](https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/commit/38646ab2d0100726d5ab591c15f22480d313c13d). If you want to try it out before the next release, you can explicitly require the `@dev` version:

```
composer require psy/psysh:@dev
```

Opening a GitHub issue for PsySH is a great way to get fixes for things like this!

Comment: Never been an issue for me before until recently. I've tried installing what you've attached, I get the following error: `Terminfo file  does not exist.` which is funny because without installing the package I get the same error.

Comment: It's never been an issue until recently because PsySH only recently started looking for terminfo by default. This is a recent bug :) The dev version _should_ have a fix for you, so if that's not working can you open a ticket in the PsySH repo so we can sort it out? https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh

Comment: No worries @bobthecow, I've created a Github issue at https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/issues/722 with a consolidated set of details with everything I've tried from this discussion and my own findings with screenshot.